# PHP get the position of a array parent

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

Here a have a json string, and need to get all the parent array positions of `registratition_id`
E.g. i want  the array at the end to out put something like this:

```
 [0] =>0
 [1] =>1
 [2] =>3
```

In fact I want to get all the arrays position which contain `registration_id`

```
$json_raw = '{"multicast_id":6446899316497614986,
                     "success":5,
                     "failure":1,
                     "canonical_ids":3,
                     "results":[
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                               "message_id":"0:1396175384218906%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                              "message_id":"0:1396175384218155%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"message_id":"0:1396175384218718%b91f4d1ff9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                              "message_id":"0:1396175384219100%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"message_id":"0:1396175384219927%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"error":"InvalidRegistration"
                             }]
                       }';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop and check if registration_id `isset`

```
$obj = json_decode($json_raw);
$resultsWithRegID = array();

foreach($obj->results as $index=>$element){
  if(isset($element->registration_id)){
     $resultsWithRegID[] = $index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative version:

```
$array_raw = json_decode($json_raw, true);

$what = "registration_id";

$res = array_keys(array_filter($array_raw['results'], function($item) use ($what)
{
    return isset($item[$what]);
}));

var_dump($res);
```

Obviously you can:

- define the key to search straight inside the `isset($item["registration_id"])`
- omit the wrapping function `array_keys` if you need the *whole part* of the array filtered

(*whole part*)

```
array (size=3)
    0 => 
        array (size=2)
            'registration_id' => 'APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv...'
            'message_id' => ''
    1 => 
        array (size=2)
            'registration_id' => 'APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv...' 
            'message_id' => '0:1396175384218155%50b5570df9fd7ecd'
    3 =>
        array (size=2)
            'registration_id' => 'APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv...'
            'message_id' => '0:1396175384219100%50b5570df9fd7ecd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert JSON to Array - Rest is yours:

```
$array = json_decode($json_raw, true);

// results with registration_id
$results = array();
foreach($array['results'] as $index => $element) {
  if(isset($element['registration_id']) === true) {
     $results[] = $index;
  }
}

var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $json_raw = '{"multicast_id":6446899316497614986,
                     "success":5,
                     "failure":1,
                     "canonical_ids":3,
                     "results":[
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                               "message_id":"0:1396175384218906%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                              "message_id":"0:1396175384218155%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"message_id":"0:1396175384218718%b91f4d1ff9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"registration_id":"APA91bEgLFvrc0lnXqX3C1euQohdHrv_wbxtGP86ezRzGWEVMQPpJjw1GMhGzfkI8Q34TU1KRts2j_-7CyU4ce6MlX5DB3umpXDGl-Ebmg53b44UKga79ee9Sal6gT_9rP3KIz9pDEUk2JVJsQmxiWXWoIfrYEAmFg",
                              "message_id":"0:1396175384219100%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"message_id":"0:1396175384219927%50b5570df9fd7ecd"
                             },
                             {"error":"InvalidRegistration"
                             }]
                       }';
$data=json_decode ($json_raw);
$arr= $data->{'results'};
$i=0;
$n_r=array();
foreach($arr as $d)
{$n_r[]=$arr[$i]->{'registration_id'};
$i=$i+1;}
print_r($n_r);
?>
</body>
</html>
```